# Llamar metodo desde Child a Parent en Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, component

Estoy creando un proceso de recuperación de cuenta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo 3 componentes 
`Email`, `Validación` y `Actualizar`

Pero necesito enviar al parent que cambie de estado. es decir al momento de enviar los datos de Email, qué este pase a Validación. Esto lo tengo en el parent de la siguiente manera:

> parent

```
data() {
      return {
        pageTotal: 3,
        pageSelected: 1,
        stepList: [
            'Email',
            'Validación',
            'Actualizar'
        ]
      }
    }
```

En mi componente `SendEmail` tengo lo siguiente:

> child

```
onSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()
    let sendForm = {route: 'recovery', data: JSON.stringify(this.form)}
    this.$store.dispatch('post', sendForm).then(response => {

         //Llamar metodo de parent para que cambie de pagina.

    }).catch(error => {
       console.warn(error)
    })
    },
```

Alguien sabe como puedo llamar cualquier método desde el child?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres usando la propiedad `$parent` asi:

```
onSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()
    let sendForm = {route: 'recovery', data: JSON.stringify(this.form)}
    this.$store.dispatch('post', sendForm).then(response => {

         //Llamar metodo de parent para que cambie de pagina.
         this.$parent.metodoParaCambiardePagina();

    }).catch(error => {
       console.warn(error)
    })
    },
```

Comment: Simple y funcional, thanks bro!